# How to Fix Token error Malformed auth code in production

Tags: javascript, express, oauth-2.0, passport.js, production-environment

So basically I am trying to use passport.js in my application and it works as expected in development
but when I push my code in production it gives error say Token Error : malformed auth code

Error looks like this

```
TokenError: Malformed auth code.
    at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy.parseErrorResponse (/var/task/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:373:12)
    at Strategy.OAuth2Strategy._createOAuthError (/var/task/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:420:16)
    at /var/task/node_modules/passport-oauth2/lib/strategy.js:177:45
    at /var/task/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:191:18
    at passBackControl (/var/task/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:132:9)
    at IncomingMessage.<anonymous> (/var/task/node_modules/oauth/lib/oauth2.js:157:7)
    at IncomingMessage.emit (node:events:539:35)
    at endReadableNT (node:internal/streams/readable:1345:12)
    at processTicksAndRejections (node:internal/process/task_queues:83:21)
```

I am Trying to fix this error and its my fourth day
I have tried almost everything
. setting access_type : 'offline',
. decodeUri
nothing works

```
const express = require('express');
const router = express.Router();
const passport = require('passport');
const { auth, requestdecode } = require('../middleware/reqAuth');
require('../config/passportAuth');
const { signToken } = require('../middleware/jwt');

router.get('/failed', (req, res) => {
    res.status(401).json({
        success: false,
        message: 'failure'
    });
});

router.post('/success', auth, (req, res) => {
    res.status(200).json({
        success: true,
        message: 'successful',
        user: req.user
    });
});

router.get(
    '/google',
    passport.authenticate('google', {
        scope: ['email', 'profile'],
        session: false,
        accessType: 'offline',
        prompt: 'consent'
    })
);

router.get(
    '/google/callback',
    passport.authenticate('google', {
        session: false,
        failureRedirect: '/failed'
    }),
    function (req, res) {
        try {
            const token = signToken(req);
            res
                .cookie('jwt_auth', token, {
                    maxAge: 11 * 60 * 60 * 1000,
                    httpOnly: false,
                    sameSite: false
                })
                .redirect(process.env.CLIENT_URL);
        } catch (err) {
            throw err;
        }
    }
);

router.get('/logout', (req, res) => {
    req.session = null;
    req.logout();
    res.redirect('/auth/google');
});

module.exports = router;
```

```
require('dotenv').config();
const passport = require('passport');
const GoogleStrategy = require('passport-google-oauth20').Strategy;
const User = require('../model/user');

passport.serializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.deserializeUser(function (user, done) {
    done(null, user);
});

passport.use(
    new GoogleStrategy(
        {
            clientID: process.env.CLIENT,
            clientSecret: process.env.CLIENT_SECRET,
            callbackURL: process.env.CALLBACK_URL,
            userProfileURL: 'https://www.googleapis.com/oauth2/v3/userinfo',
            accessType: 'offline',
            passReqToCallback: true
        },
        async function (request, accessToken, refreshToken, profile, done) {
            console.log(request);
            try {
                let existingUser = await User.findOne({ oauthId: profile.id });
                if (!existingUser) {
                    const newUser = await User.create({
                        oauthId: profile.id,
                        name: profile.displayName,
                        email: profile.emails[0].value,
                        imageLink: profile.photos[0].value
                    });
                    return done(null, newUser);
                }
                done(null, existingUser);
            } catch (error) {
                console.log(error);
            }
        }
    )
);
```

Please somebody Help

I can't understand why it works in development but not in production
here is the url https://cloudy-newt-fashion.cyclic.app

code -https://github.com/atulchourasiya/QuickNote

Comment: Not sure if you already solved the issue but If you have tokens already created and the api server gets restarted you will still have the old tokens which will give you malformed error, so you need to re-create/request new tokens for each client after each restart of the api server. I'm trying to figure out how to solve that behaviour :(